# Build correct JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jbuilder

I try to render a correct formatted json:

```
   render json: {photo: @photo.as_json(with_thumbs_url: true)}
```

In my model I have to do this:

```
  def as_json(options={})
    if options[:with_thumbs_url].present?
      Jbuilder.encode do |json| 
        json.(self, :id, :beschreibung, :date, :art) 
        json.thumbs self.photo_thumbs.map{|e| e.file.url(:medium)}
      end
    end
  end
```

My problem is that like this it returns:

```
 {photo: "{"id":288,"beschreibung":"Anfang","date" ...system/photos/6267/medium/136.webp?1413823129"]}"}
```

What i dont like about this JSON is that `photo` in the Json is rendered as String:

```
        "{"id":288,"beschreibung":"
```

I would prefer to have it not encoded, for example like this:

```
  {photo: {id: "288", beschreibung: "Anfang" ...
```

I would say the problem is my code: The `encode`:

```
   Jbuilder.encode do |json|
```

So in order fix my problem i tried:

```
   Jbuilder.new do |json|
```

But then I get a error in:

```
   render json: {photo: @photo.as_json(with_thumbs_url: true)}

   wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
```

What do I wrong and how can I fix my code? Thanks

Comment: try the active model serializers gem, much much easy to output json https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work i had to change my code to:

```
def as_json
  Jbuilder.new do |json|
    # your stuff
  end.attributes!
end
```